# I need help coding a string so that the output will be like a triangle but with the last letter first

Tags: java, string, for-loop, methods, string-length

o

lo

llo

ello

Hello
This is the output i want

i tried using

`for(int i = l.length(); i>=1; i--){`
`(int k =; k<=i; k++){`    
`System.out.print(l.substring(l.lenght()-k))`;

Comment: what output did you get when you ran your code?

Answer (score 1):

You just need one loop:

```
String l = "Hello";
for(int i = l.length()-1; i>=0; i--){ 
  System.out.println(l.substring(i));
}
```

Output:

```
o
lo
llo
ello
Hello
```